Weird SMS. Help!
Help me decipher this weird SMS I got:
8 6 777 9 7777 2 6 33 7 555 222 8 444 6 33
This must be some kind of cipher, right?

If we

 use an old-fashioned mobile phone keyboard, or indeed a really old-fashioned dial-phone, where each digit corresponds to a group of letters and repeating the digit advances through that group (1 means something else; 2=A, 22=B, 222=C; 3=D, 33=E, etc.), then we get: TMRWSAMEPLCTIME

so I think whoever sent the message

 would like to see you again tomorrow, at the same place and time.


Ways that a puzzle can make you feel old #27

Didn't the letters start with the 2 key? 2=A, 22=B, 222=C?

Yup. Which I knew when decoding but had already forgotten when writing the explanation :-). Will fix. [EDITED to add:] Fixed now. Thanks.

@Stiv yea, immediately I could recognize this puzzle is about that, and this was really common back then. This puzzle coming back now means it's old enough already that it's now a novel puzzle again

It's called a multi-tap cipher which is derived from the method @GarethMcCaughan described in his answer.
You can get more details on this cipher here - https://www.dcode.fr/multitap-abc-cipher
